# Jupyter notebook exclamation mark arguments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In `jupyter notebook`, we can execute a shell command using the exclamation mark, such as:

```
!ls *.png
```

I am looking for a way to pass arguments to this command, something like:

```
extention='*.png'
!ls %extention
```

I know this is possible using [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) or [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), but I want to use the exclamation mark as this will give me live output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible using `{}`, such as:

```
extention='*.png'
!ls {extention}
```

Comment: It does not work in my case. Could you give a prompt what may be a reason?